# Perform GET request with an XML parameter (PHP cURL)

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to implement [this](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/updaterecords.html) API method and sending a GET request using PHP cURL.

Here is my code:

```
    $url = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/'.$module.'/'.$method.'?authtoken='.config('app.ZOHO_KEY').'&scope=crmapi&newFormat=1&id='.$record_id.'&xmlData='.$XML_data;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
```

The URL computes to this:

```
https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Contacts/updateRecords?authtoken=XXXX&scope=crmapi&newFormat=1&id=2410575000000139003&xmlData= <Contacts> <row no="1"> <FL val="Email Opt Out">true</FL> </row> </Contacts>
```

However, the request fails. I have tried `str_replace(' ', '%20', $url)` but this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: data is sent in body not in url

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried str_replace(' ', '%20', $url)

You do this wrong. Proper tool for the task is [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

**EDIT**

You should refactor your code and sent this data via regular POST request, which is exactly what is it for.

Comment: I have tried that as well using  `$ch = curl_init(urlencode($url))`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is being caused by line breaks and also `urlencode()` does not work because I have `/` in my XML structure and I need to keep them.

Comment: why you sends this via GET instead of POST then?